# Join elem with next one in a functional style

Tags: list, algorithm, scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to find a way to "join"/"groupby" 2 elements in a list as following :

```
List("a","b","c","d")  -> List("ab","bc","cd")
```

With a functional style.

Would someone know how to do this?

Need I use reducer, fold, scan, other higher-order function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sliding](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#sliding(size:Int,step:Int):Iterator[Repr]) creates subcollections with sliding window, then you just need to map this sublists to strings:

```
List("a","b","c","d").sliding(2,1).map{case List(a,b) => a+b}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
val xs = List("a","b","c","d")
(xs, xs.tail).zipped.map(_ ++ _) // List(ab, bc, cd)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sliding` to create a window:

```
val l = List("a","b","c","d")
val res = l.sliding(2).map(_.reduce(_ + _))
res.foreach(println)
```

this results with

```
ab
bc
cd
```